# Server doesn't listen (PosgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, tcp, pgadmin

I'm getting **Server doesn't listen** (Img1) every time a try to connect to *db* server in **pgAdmin III**. It started after a network adjustment related to local machines IP number in our company.

I'm also receiving **Error connecting to the server**. (Img2)

[image: Img1]

[image: Img2]

Here's `pg_hba.conf` file and the ip adress of the computer.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked whether the ip addresses in the `pg_hba.conf` are still valid?

Comment: the file `pg_hba.conf` is as in the image.

Comment: Are server and client in the same machine? If not, try to add this line to your pg_hba  :  `host all all 10.10.13.233/24 md5`. Afterwards, either restart the database or execute this function `SELECT pg_reload_conf()`.

Comment: also make sure the `listen_addresses` at the `postgresql.conf` is properly configured, e.g. `listen_addresses = '*'`

Comment: They're not in the same machine. I added the line and restarted my machine, but, unfortunately, the problem still goes on. Also checked the `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: That's puzzling. If the ip addresses are properly added to the pg_hba and the server is listening `*`, the only option that crosses my mind would be that there is a firewall not letting your connection to go through... which has happened to me many times before.

Comment: Yes, and windows firewall is down. Do you think the problem may be coming from the *db* server that i'm trying to connect with? Would be valid to restart it or something?

Comment: It's hard to tell, since I have no access to your network. But I do recall having the same issue to establish a connection with postgres and the problem was actually in the firewall. Restart wouldn't help much, if the firewall rules are not allowing you to reach the server from your station.